# Bat file for Windows 10 Custom Start Menu

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a `.bat` file, *(which makes a custom start menu from a custom `.xml` file)*, to deploy to a group of machines.

Here is what I got:

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "&Import-StartLayout –LayoutPath C:\Installs\StartMenu.xml –MountPath $env:SystemDrive\"
```

When I run the `PowerShell` command itself it works but for some reason I cannot get it to work from the `.bat` file.

Comment: You should use the proper syntax, `PowerShell.exe -Command "& {<command>}"` although your example may also work by removing the leading ampersand, **`&`**.`

Comment: I also note that your code uses the character **`–`** instead of **`-`** and there's probably nothing stopping you from using `-MountPath %SystemDrive%\ `either!

Comment: I tried removing the ampersand and if I do it in a command prompt it says the string is missing the terminator: +categoryinfo and +fullyqualifiederrorid

Comment: Did you try the braces method, the proper **`-`** character and even changing to `%SystemDrive%`? It would also help were you to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49942585/edit) to include the attempts you've now made and the results returned from them.

Comment: So what should the whole thing be, I'm not sure what you are referring to by the proper - character.

Comment: If you take a look at the character preceding `Command` in your code, _(it is correct)_, then take a look at those preceding both `LayoutPath` and `MountPath`, you'll see that they are different, you should replace them. I also showed you how to use the braces in my first comment. _You'd obviously replace `<command>` with the command which you stated works when not ran from the batch file_.

Comment: Ok I may have got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my comments, put together as an answer:

```bat
PowerShell -C "&{Import-StartLayout -LayoutPath C:\Installs\StartMenu.xml -MountPath %SystemDrive%\}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my code to:

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "&{Import-StartLayout -LayoutPath C:\Installs\StartMenu.xml -MountPath $env:%SystemDrive%\}"
```

The suggestions from Compo seemed to work.

Comment: Methinks this needs to be either `$Env:SystemDrive` or `%SystemDrive%`.